# PostgreSQL and Heroku, find and group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to get an app to run on Heroku properly. (Heroku uses the postgreSQL database, yeh?)

In development, I'm using sqlite, and this is my code in a controller =>

```
@productsort = Products.find(:all,
                             :select => 'count(*) count, color',
                             :group => 'color', 
                             :order => 'count DESC', 
                             :conditions => 'size = "Small"')
```

As you can see, I'm trying to group products by their colors, and order them by greatest amount to least.

Also, the products must be "Small". (the conditions)

In SQL, it works fine.

But not in PostgreSQL (heroku).

This is from running "heroku log"

```
2011-06-20T18:20:33+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  column "Small" does not exist

2011-06-20T18:20:33+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...ducts".* FROM "products" WHERE (size = "Smal...
```

Hm... I've searched around and I couldn't find anything similar to what I have.

All help would be appreicated. Thank you

Comment: Do yourself a favor and install PostgreSQL to develop on if you're deploying to Heroku. Developing on top of one database but deploying on another is a recipe for pain, suffering, and confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be using single quotes around your strings in the conditions (double quotes may work with sqlite, but they definitely don't with PostgreSQL).

So replace your conditions with this:

```
:conditions => "size = 'Small'"
```

It will still work in SQLite too.

Comment: Right, double quotes in PostgreSQL are for quoting identifiers, not for quoting string values.